# How do I fix or get rid of ESLint definition requirement in ASP.NET Razor app?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor, eslint

I just upgraded an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor app to 2.1 to get the new functionality for EF Core 2.1.  This is my first major project in ASP.NET coming from a WinForms & PHP background.

I'm trying to go through and clear out the error list, but I'm getting ESLint errors, and I've never used ESLint before so I don't know where to start.  Google isn't too helpful on this issue either.

Here's the warnings:

```
Warning react/jsx-sort-prop-types   (ESLint) Definition for rule 'react/jsx-sort-prop-types' was not found
Warning react/wrap-multilines   (ESLint) Definition for rule 'react/wrap-multilines' was not found
Warning react/require-extension (ESLint) Definition for rule 'react/require-extension' was not found
```

I don't even know what these mean, googling them doesn't enlighten me, and they don't seem to point to a specific line of code.

What the hell are these warnings trying to tell me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you **are** using ESLint, and don't want to add code to all your files, then you can disable the three rules in your ESLint configuration file.  There are actually two ways to do this.

The long way is to find the configuration file, which is at c:\Users{username}.eslintrc  You can open it with a text editor, find the rule and set the value to 0 (zero), which means disabled.  For example:

```
"react/jsx-sort-prop-types": 0,
```

The shorter way is to go to Tools/Options/Text Editor/'JavaScript/TypeScript'/Linting/General.  On that page is a button 'Reset global .eslintrc'.  If you click that you get a newer version of the .eslintrc configuration file that doesn't have these rules in at all, assuming you have a recent version of Visual Studio.

Whichever method you use you'll need to restart Visual Studio, and after that the errors should go away.

I think the problem is arising because you (and I) have an old version of this file (.eslintrc) with rules that aren't supported or no longer work for the React plugin that ships with ESLint for Visual Studio.  I was getting these errors in projects that had no npm modules installed, and definitely no React.  I think upgrades to Visual Studio probably don't overwrite this file in case you've changed it.

It's also possible to put a .eslintrc file into your project folder and it will override the settings in the default location.  So for an enterprise project where you're seeing this issue on multiple machines you could just check in an .eslintrc that fixed it.  However, if you do a clean install of Visual Studio on a new machine I don't think you'll see the problem, so I'm not sure that should be necessary.

I used Visual Studio 2017 15.8.1 to test this.  ESLint got quite a big [upgrade in 15.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#eslint-improvements).

Comment: That was exactly it.  Thanks for the descriptive answer!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep using EsLint (which is good), You can disable and reenable EsLint at the start of the .js files to avoid those warnings and still have EsLint checks avaliable for the rest of the file:

/* eslint-disable */

/* eslint-enable */

And for files that you don't control like jquery.js, bootstrap.js, etc you can just disable completely with this line at the start of the file:

/* eslint-disable */

You just need to remember to add again this line after you have updated them.

Comment: Can you explain (or post a link) why that works?  If these are legitimate errors, then I want to correct them properly.  But even if it's just a known bug with ESLint, I'm building an enterprise system, so I there's a LOT of files that would need this treatment, unless I could put it in the _Layout.cshtml or something.

Comment: It just stops eslint for the start of the .js file them resumes it after it has checked the start of the file. I got those from https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring . To be honest I don't know about those messages. It's probably is a bug since I don't use react. 

Yes, you are right it would be a big hassle for an enterprise system. I made it for my project and I had to change 30-40 .js files, it took a while but I was able to remove all warnings.

Comment: This worked great for me. Thanks! Quick note to others, the enable/disable does need to be the first two lines in the file. You can include other disable rules after this if you need to modify the rules further on the file.

Answer (score 2):

If you're NOT using ESLint, and you are using Visual Studio, you can go to:

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript/TypeScript -> Linting -> General.

From there you can uncheck the "Enable ESLint" checkbox, and check the global configuration file for that tool.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 (15.8.4), to find this menu.

[image]

Comment: If you are supposed to be using ESLint for this project, looks like this is the page for the React plugin for it:  https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react

Comment: This is my workaround for the problem for now.  But I would like to have validation on my scripts, so I am looking for a more permanent solution.

Comment: Did the documentation for the React plugin help? I'm assuming you're using that, but don't know a lot about it myself.

Comment: No... I'm not explicitly using React.  Maybe it's built into the project like Bootstrap?

Comment: I don't believe so. But it is probably coming with one of your dependencies. If it's not the focus of your work, I wouldn't worry about it. You can always go back and learn about these specific rules/plugin, if/when you want to do that.